# SQLite size increase day-by-day even no content in it

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have one doubt that is - I am using SQLite database for Some ERP kind of project to android platform. In SQLite database I am only storing last 30 day's of data and rest will be sync to server's database. Now issue that => In my SQLite database any of table doesn't have more than 30 row but still it size increase day-by-day. So to resolve this issue i wrote a service that will be run once in week and this service will do database cleanup for me i am doing these thing

```
       public class AppServiceDBClean extends WakefulIntentService {   
int TEN_MINUTES = 10*60*1000;
public AppServiceDBClean() {
    super("AppService");     
}       

@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App services", 50000).show();
    System.out.println("service for database clean ");

    try {
        doCleanUPDB();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("AppService", "Exception appending to log file", e);
    }  
}
public boolean IsSyncTriggered() {

    boolean isActive = false;
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
    Account[] ac = am.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    if (ac.length > 0) {
        isActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(ac[0], Constants.AUTHORITY);
    }
    return isActive;
}
public void doCleanUPDB(){

    /**
     * Create some basic instance of database interaction
     */

    SQLiteDatabaseWrapper databaseInstance = mycutomclass .getDatabase();
    String sql = "VACUUM;" ;
    if(!IsSyncTriggered()){
        databaseInstance.execSQL(sql);
        databaseInstance.setTransactionSuccessful();
        databaseInstance.endTransaction();
    }else{
        /**
         * If the sync is in progress
         * wait for 10 minutes and try again
         * */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TEN_MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d("DataCleaningService","SleepException ",e);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
          }
  }
```

Now i want that

```
   "VACUUM"
```

will release all unused space of all table that means - "It will cleanup my whole database" and after that it will commit this Query. Now question is that - whatever i did here it will work for my requirement or not? This service will do cleanup task for me or not.? Any suggestion is really appreciated . Thanks is advance to all.

Comment: Why don't you just try it out, since you already have a solution to play with?

Comment: @Googie.. Thanks for your response. Actually i want to know expert's view about this issue.In your opinion it will work for me or not?

Comment: And i have one another doubt that "VACUUM" will work for table or Database.

Comment: Actually, you don't need this. SQLite reuses space after deleted data, so your database will grow only to some extend. Then it should stay at the same size - more, or less.

Comment: Yup you are correct but why it happen in our project. I don't know because i am new joined this company and this project is under development from last 2 year.So i don't all aspect of this project.

Comment: This "Vacuum" is not working :(.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Maybe there's no unused space to free?

Comment: I deleted lot of row but still it size goes increasing abruptly. Some time our apk size goes to 65MB and its size is 36.02MB

Comment: Execute `PRAGMA freelist_count;` - does it return 0, or more?